# how does Monix use back-pressure with flatMap operator?

Tags: scala, backpressure, monix

Monix use Ack to sync emitted messages, but if I use groupBy and flatMap, the inner Observable not follow the back-pressure out of the `source`.

See this test code please:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

import monix.execution.Scheduler.Implicits.global
import monix.execution.Ack.Continue
import monix.reactive.{Observable, OverflowStrategy}
import org.junit.Test


class MonixBackpressureWithGroupByTest2 {
  @Test
  def test(): Unit = {
    val source = Observable.range(0,130)

    val backPressuredStream = source.map(x => {
        println("simple log first  map - " + x)
        x
      })
      .asyncBoundary(OverflowStrategy.BackPressure(5))
      .map { i =>

        println("after backpressure map, and Rim 3 operation of source - " + ((i % 3) toString) -> i)
        ((i % 3) toString) -> i
      }
      .groupBy{case (k, v) => k}
      .flatMap(x => {
        val mapWithSleep = x.map{case groupedMsg@(key, value) =>
          Thread.sleep(2000)
          println("inner Observable after group by rim 3. sleep 2 second for every message - " + groupedMsg)
          groupedMsg
        }

        mapWithSleep

      })

    backPressuredStream.share.subscribe(
      (keyAndValue: (String, Long)) => Continue
    )

    global.scheduleWithFixedDelay(0L, 1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, () => {
      println("========sleep 1 second ============")
    })

    Thread.currentThread().join()

  }

}
```

output:

```
...

========sleep 1 second ============
inner Observable after group by rim 3. sleep 2 second for every message - (0,72)
(after backpressure map, and Rim 3 operation of source - 1,73)
(after backpressure map, and Rim 3 operation of source - 2,74)
(after backpressure map, and Rim 3 operation of source - 0,75)
========sleep 1 second ============
========sleep 1 second ============
inner Observable after group by rim 3. sleep 2 second for every message - (0,75)
(after backpressure map, and Rim 3 operation of source - 1,76)
(after backpressure map, and Rim 3 operation of source - 2,77)
(after backpressure map, and Rim 3 operation of source - 0,78)
========sleep 1 second ============
========sleep 1 second ============
inner Observable after group by rim 3. sleep 2 second for every message - (0,78)
(after backpressure map, and Rim 3 operation of source - 1,79)
...
```

Which appear some backpressure not match well:
after: `sleep 2 second for every message ...` backpressure give three of item `after backpressure map -  ...`

how can `sleep 2 second for every message ...` have one to one relation with `after backpressure map - ...` in terms of back-pressure?

and another wonder: why log of `sleep 2 second for every message`  output `(0, 72), (0, 75), (0,78)` but such things `(0, 72), (1, 73), (2,74)`?

thanks.

Monix version:
  `"io.monix" %% "monix" % "3.0.0-RC1"`

Comment: Grammatical errors in your questions make it hard to understand what you're asking. As we are all humans and noone expects you to speak (or write) perfect English, can you at least try to explain it with more detail?

Comment: Maybe also instead of writing `thread -`, `2222 - ` and `=====`, make your log messages a little more descriptive so we can understand what you're trying to show.

Comment: @MarkusAppel, hi, I have do some pretty print info and variable name. Even so, sorry for English is also poor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour you see is exactly what you can expect.

To quickly summarize what your application does, let me explain it with my words:

---

You have an `Observable` generate numbers, and do some side-effect for each element.

Next, you group the elements by `_ % 3`.

Next, you do some more side-effects (sleeping and writing to console) inside of each group's `Observable`.

Then, you `flatMap` each group's `Observable`, resulting in a single, flat `Observable`.

---

So why do you in the beginning only see the first group (where `_ % 3 == 0`) print stuff to the console? ***

The answer lies in `flatMap`: When looking at the [documentation](https://monix.io/api/3.0/monix/reactive/Observable.html#concatMap[B](f:A=%3Emonix.reactive.Observable[B]):monix.reactive.Observable[B]) for `Observable`, you will find the following description for `flatMap`:

```
final def flatMap[B](f: (A) ⇒ Observable[B]): Observable[B]

Alias for concatMap.

[...]
```

Think of `Observable`s like you would think about `List`s for a second: When you concat `List`s, you will end up with a single `List` containing first the elements of the first `List`, followed by the elements of the second `List`, and so on.

In Monix, the same behaviour is achieved for `Observable` by waiting for the first `Observable` produced inside a `flatMap` (read: `concatMap`) operation to send the "completed" - signal. Only then will the second `Observable` be consumed, and so on.

**Or, simply put, `flatMap` cares about the sequence of the produced `Observable`s.**

But when do the `Observable`s in *your* `flatMap` operation "complete"? For this we have to understand how `groupBy` works - because that's where they come from.

For `groupBy` to work although `Observable`s are lazily evaluated it has to store incoming elements in a buffer. I am not 100% sure on this, but if `groupBy` works like I think it does, it will, for any grouped `Observable` that pulls the next element, go through the original `Observable` indefinitely until it finds an element belonging to that very group, saving all prior (but not yet required) elements belonging to other groups in that buffer for later use.

All of this means that `groupBy` cannot know if all elements of a group have been found until the source `Observable` signals completion, then it will use all remaining buffered elements and then signal completion to the grouped `Observable`s.

**In simpler words: `Observable`s produced by `groupBy` do not complete until the source `Observable` completes.**

When pulling all this information together you will understand that only when the source Observable (your `Observable.range(0, 130)`) has been completed, the first grouped `Observable` will be completed as well, and because of `flatMap` only then all other grouped `Observable`s will be used.

Because I know from your last question that you're trying to build a web socket, using `flatMap` is a bad idea - your source `Observable` of incoming requests will *never* complete, effectively only serving the very first IP address you will come across.

**What you have to do instead is use `mergeMap`.** When comparing to `concatMap` `mergeMap` does not care about the sequence of elements, instead the "first come first served" - rule applies.

---

*** : When you reach the end of my explanation and hopefully understand how `groupBy` and `flatMap` works, you will understand why I wrote "in the beginning"!

Comment: Thanks for your patient! The problem is occurred, like what you said, when building a socket library. Hold in [github](https://github.com/LoranceChen/RxSocket).`mergeMap` is good choice for every socket as one Observable of the grouped event. And another thinking about groupBy is how to unsubscribe disconnected socket avoid buffer useless Observable if remote address as group key?

Comment: @LoranceChen I think that very much depends how you wrap the socket into an `Observable` in the first place. But if you merge the grouped `Observable`s you won't be able to unsubscribe to single groups - because there is only one `Subscriber` for everything. But you might not have to unsubscribe afterall - it won't bring any real improvement. Still, in your Socket -> `Observable` - implementation you could probably send a completed signal once the socket closes.